# Facebook Comment Box and Messenger

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-comments

I am trying to add `Facebook Comment Box` as well as `Messenger Plugin` in my Angular/Ionic App (PWA).

The Messenger plugin when included separately works well. But with the following code, where I try to combine both, the Messenger fails to load, with no errors in console.

index.html

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id + '1';
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=1423348794345669&autoLogAppEvents=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution="setup_tool"
    page_id="838973246246775"
    greeting_dialog_display="hide"
    logged_in_greeting="Hi! How can we help you?"
    logged_out_greeting="Hi! How can we help you?">
</div>
```

Messenger only working code @ https://change.grassrootsapp.in/
Combined broken code @ https://alpha4.uat.grassrootsapp.in/

chat.html

```
<ion-content id="event-chat-content" *ngIf="cEvent">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-comments" [attr.data-href]="cEvent.shortURL" data-numposts="10"></div>
</ion-content>
```

chat.ts (from https://blog.f5.works/using-facebook-comment-plugin-in-angular-2/)

```
ionViewDidEnter() {

    // https://samkirkiles.svbtle.com/angular-4-facebook-login-integration
    let wind                =   <any>window;
    if (wind.FB) {
        wind.FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
}
```

Now to combine both, I am unsure

- where to put
- how to include `script` tag for `sdk.js` as well as `xfbml.customerchat.js`

I tried the following scenario and it fails:

- Have my `index.html` undisturbed.
- Remove just `<div id="fb-root"></div>` from chat.html, as its already included in `index.html`
- With this, when I load the app, the messenger works fine.
- But when I navigate to the component which has Comment box, it's not loading the Comment box and also break the Messenger.

Any help?

Comment: Constantly deleting the FB object and re-adding the SDK is nonsense to begin with. To do that properly first off all, go check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171692/angularjs-and-facebook-comments

Comment: I should have known. Updated my code with a better logic.